# Kivy: Use a toggle button to change the state of another toggle button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

For example, in Kivy language:

```
<MainToggle@ToggleButton>:
    on_state: # something that will change the state of the sub-toggle

<SubToggle@ToggleButton>:
    on_state: self.background_color = 0,0,0,1 # the sub-toggle button changes color
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to other Widgets using the kivy id system. Observe the following code:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
<MainToggle@ToggleButton>:

<SubToggle@ToggleButton>:
    on_state: self.background_color = 0,0,0,1 # the sub-toggle button changes color 

BoxLayout:
    MainToggle:
        id: my_toggle1 # an id allows us to refer to this widget
        text: "Main Toggle"
        # change the other toggle's state using its id 
        on_state: my_toggle2.state = "down" if my_toggle2.state == "normal" else "normal"
    SubToggle:
        id: my_toggle2
        text: "Sub Toggle"
            """))
```

Here's a superb [video](https://youtu.be/ZVWAKzR63ig?t=5m31s) tutorial that uses the kivy id system in a practical example. Reply if you are having trouble wrapping your head around this.

Comment: Great! This worked, thanks for the help. One further problem that I'm encountering though is when I try to use 'MainToggle' to change the state of multiple 'SubToggle' buttons, not just one. I tried to achieve this by giving all the SubToggle buttons the same id, however the MainToggle only seems to affect one SubToggle at a time. Any thoughts on this? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, you're trying to do something tricky here it seems, are you sure you have chosen the right way to do this? Anyway, if there are many SubToggle buttons and you want to change them in the same way, why don't you give your BoxLayout an id and, as you insert SubToggles from the Python code, add them to a ListProperty. Then you can loop through that list and do `for sub in sub_list: change_state(x)` or something like that. Consider accepting my original answer if it helped you.

Comment: Just accepted it :) Yeah, what I'm trying to do is have a list of items under a menu. I want to be able to click on item buttons individually, and also click on the menu button so that it changes the states of all the item buttons below it into the 'down' position. I have been inserting all of my toggle buttons using kivy language, but it does seem like I need to make a loop of some sort on the Python side.

Comment: If you don't have too many SubToggles, just consider giving each one a seperate id and then have the MainToggle change each of the SubToggle's state individually - that's just as a valid solution as I proposed with a ListProperty. The list one is just a bit cleaner and you won't have to do anything if you add another SubToggle in the future. I recommend you start with the individual id approach first if you're having doubts.